# pyp2p library - How to use the pyp2p library for peer to peer communication

Tags: python, p2p, nat

Can anyone please tell me how to use the pyp2p library for peer to peer communication. Or is there any other way to connect to 2 different computers which are behind 2 different NATs

```
Alice Node

from pyp2p.net import *
import time

#Setup Alice's p2p node.
alice = Net(passive_bind="192.168.0.45", passive_port=44444, interface="eth0:2", node_type="passive", debug=1)
alice.start()
alice.bootstrap()
alice.advertise()

#Event loop.
while 1:
    for con in alice:
        for reply in con:
            print(reply)

    time.sleep(1)
```

What must I enter under passive_bind, passive_port and interface to establish connection between the two nodes which are behind 2 different NATs

```
Bob Node

from pyp2p.net import *

#Setup Bob's p2p node.
bob = Net(passive_bind="192.168.0.44", passive_port=44445, interface="eth0:1", node_type="passive", debug=1)
bob.start()
bob.bootstrap()
bob.advertise()

#Event loop.
while 1:
    for con in bob:
        con.send_line("test")

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.